# C# Function in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have heard that it is possible to write a function in C# and then somehow import that into SQL Server to call in T-SQL scripts.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is called ORM? Look for Entity Framework or NHibernate.

Comment: CLR stored procs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: Search for CLR Stored Procedures

Comment: It would be better to just write these stored procedures and store them on your server. +1 for bringing this to my attention, though. I'd never heard of [CLR Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are known as CLR Functions.  I have never used them, but generally it is recommended to avoid them where possible.  I believe that has mostly to do with maintainability than anything else, although there may be performance issues in some instances.

Just do a quick Google on "SQL CLR" and you will get plenty.

[The MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx)

Comment: In some instances they can improve performance.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was after.  I had no idea what the name was and so no idea what to Google.  I don't know why I have so many negative votes.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, I suppose that is true, but like I said, I have no experience with them.  Although this question in particular gives a good insight to the attitude of the community here.  Very interesting.

Comment: @SachinKainth I'd say your question was overly broad but, its good you got the information you needed.

Comment: @DaveJohnson, the main thrust of your answer is right but could have been a comment. That's more to do with the question I guess. You should avoid padding your answer with conjecture that is not based on experience. +1 anyway.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, although until just now I did not have the ability to comment on the OP, only on my own answers/questions.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - You say it is generally recommended to avoid CLR Functions -- can you provide a citation?  Who says that and for what reasons?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - not much in the way of citation, just what I have seen elsewhere in various blogs and forums.  Outside of Joe Celko I have never seen anyone say "HOLY CRAP WHY ARE YOU USING CLR FOR ANYTHING?!11".  Every time I have seen mention of not using them it is for maintainability reasons.  Interesting links: https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/09/29/time-for-a-rethink-on-sql-clr/ and http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/495145-sql-server-2005-clr-functions-vs-sql-functions

Comment: Here is a blog I recall reading in the past contributing to my conjecture on whether or not CLR's should be used.  Mixed bag, I agree.  And, as mentioned, I will need to learn to keep my conjecture to myself around here.  https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/06/welcome-to-the-jungle-clr